# OJS 3.0.1 is not sending any emails

Tags: smtp, phpmailer, sendmail, ojs

I have a new installation of OJS 3.0.1. I am new to OJS so I apologize if my question is simple. I log in as the manager and create a journal. I tell it to send email to my address but I never receive it. . When I try to send from OJS there is nothing in the maillog . in OJS in the classes/mail folder there are only 1 php files. Is that correct.
Also, is there an easier way to test sending mail from OJS

Answer (score 1):

[Please see the documentation:](https://github.com/pkp/ojs/blob/de34b20784bd38fcf04ffdf298d1e322a135a4ab/docs/FAQ)

> 3) Emails sent out by the system are never received.
>
> A: By default, OJS sends mail through PHP's built-in mail() facility.
>
> On Windows PHP needs to be configured to send email through a SMTP
>   server    (running either on the same machine or on another machine).
>          On other platforms such as Linux and Mac OS X, PHP will sent mail using the    local sendmail client, so a local MTA such as
>   Sendmail or Postfix must be    running and configured to allow
>   outgoing mail.
>          See http://www.php.net/mail for more details on configuring PHP's mail    functionality.
>          OJS can also be configured to use an SMTP server as specified in    config.inc.php, either with or without authentication.

There are many ways to configure email for OJS. There are advantages and disadvantages all around. Using Gmail for SMTP is simple to set up, but it does not give you the ability to direct emails to individual associate editors. If you want fine grained control, you need to run your own mail server, and that takes some setting up. Also, with your own mail server, spam filtering becomes a problem. For our installation, we had to send email from OJS to our own email server (same domain) and then forward to external addresses. If we sent directly from OJS to external addresses, spam filters would block the email b/c OJS wants to impersonate your email address while sending it from another domain (you solve this by creating an email address in the same domain as OJS so the email headers aren't spoofed this way).

You can see specific examples of email set ups [here](https://forum.pkp.sfu.ca/). Reviewing these might answer your question or help you ask a more specific one.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 easy ways to setup Open Journal System (OJS) email

1. config.inc.php
2. PHPMailer.php

**config.inc.php**

Open config.inc.php (public_html/config.inc.php), uncomment and configure the following lines

```
smtp = On
smtp_server = mail.domain.com
smtp_port = 465
smtp_auth = ssl
smtp_username = info@domain.com (your email)
smtp_password = ***********     (your password)
```

you can confirm smtp_server and smtp_port through cpanel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJRSa.jpg)

**PHPMailer.php**

Open PHPMailer.php (public_html/lib/pkp/lib/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php) and configure the following

```
public $From = 'info@domain.com';
public $FromName = 'User';
public $Host = 'ssl://smtp.domain.com';
public $Port = 465;
public $Username = 'info@domain.com';
public $Password = '**************';
public $AuthType = 'ssl';
```

Answer (score 0):

In New Version of OJS-3.2.0-1 has no setting of SMTP and PHPMailer Setting. Many people worried about email notification when I debug the issue I found that no SMTP Setting  & PHPMailer.

First of all, User should check localhost Connecting with XAMPP Server. If the server has successfully sent a mail message it means localhost is working. Now you should check simple code of PHPMailer to check the Connectivity with XAMPP while PHPMailer is working

Comment: Please don't format plaintext using code blocks. It makes your answer extremely difficult to read.